# jQuery appendTo with 'broken' HTML

Tags: jquery

This is my HTML:

```
<table id="mytable">

</table>
```

When I run this code:

```
$('<tr>').appendTo('#mytable');
```

I get:

```
<table id="mytable">
<tr></tr>
</table>
```

How can I avoid jQuery's appendTo from closing my tags?

Comment: Why is that a problem for you?

Comment: What do you mean with "closing my tags"?  Which tags are getting closed?

Comment: I'm trying to append multiple strings separate lines (through different loops etc) and I want to be able to append the open tag and the closing tag outside of the loop.

Comment: You're adding elements, not strings that are HTML syntax. This is how it works. Tell us what you want to achieve instead.

Comment: That's not how `.append()` works, you want more elements inside the `<tr>` you `.append()` them to the `<tr>`.  You have to `.append()` complete HTML elements/fragments.

Comment: @Nigel Angel I'm trying to get only the ``<tr>`` inside my table, without the closing ``</tr>``

Comment: @hoverhand: Then something isn't right.

Comment: We can see that. Pretend it's impossible and tell us, instead, how you want to manipualte your table.

Comment: That's not what `$('<tr>')` does. But you can always create a string with what you want and then use that inside `append()` later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. jQuery works on the DOM, which is a layer above the raw HTML. It consists of nodes which can only be valid.

If you want to append things to the row, use this:

```
var myRow = $('<tr />').appendTo('#mytable');
for( whatever ) {
    $('<td />').appendTo(myRow).text( 'this is my cell! woo!' );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment above, you can always create a string and then use that string in your `append()`:

```
var myString = "<tr><td>Hello World!</td></tr>";
$('.inner').append(myString);
```

However, I would recommend against it and always create valid elements individually.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no reason to prevent jQuery from closing your  tag in the first place.

If you're trying to append a `<tr>`, then add whatever comes inside the tag, then append a closing `</tr>`, you should instead use the clone method.

In the HTML:

```
<tr class="tr-template"></tr>
```

In the jQuery:

```
$( 'tr-template' )
  .clone()
  .removeClass('tr-template')
  .html( 'whatever you want inside the tr' )
  .appendTo('#mytable');
```

Comment: Or just use a real JS templating library.

Comment: it's more likely that he wants to add `td` tags than text to the row, so you should suggest `.html` rather than `.text`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something more like this:

```
var tableData = '<tr>';

tableData += "<td>One</td>";
tableData += "<td>Two</td>";
tableData += "<td>Three</td>";

tableData += "</tr>";

$('#mytable').html(tableData);
```

Construct a string of HTML, inject that string into the table.